# AnchorPane shows a white border when setResizable is false (JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx-2, javafx

My problem is that when I use setResizable(false) one white border is shown on my scene.
When I don't set it false works fine, but I need to set it false.

Code:

```
 Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());  

        LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager(scene);
        loginManager.showLoginScreen();
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
```

My ImageView is inside of my AnchorPane

```
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="600.0" prefWidth="900.0" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml" fx:controller="br.com.facilit.target.app.desktop.view.MainViewController">
  <children>
    <ImageView id="background" fitHeight="600.0" fitWidth="900.0" pickOnBounds="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="@../images/background.jpg" preserveRatio="true" smooth="true" />
      </image>
```

[image]

Comment: your root node is Anchorpane in FXML , then why you created StackPane as root in code?

Comment: It doesn't matter, I still having the same problem

Comment: Hi, I also have the same problem, it remember me the space needed by a scrollbar.

Comment: don't hard-code sizing constraints ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue, I resolved in this way:

```
primaryStage.setScene(scene);

primaryStage.setWidth(900);
primaryStage.setHeight(600);
primaryStage.setResizable(false);

primaryStage.show();
```

You have to set the scene *before* setting the resizable property and set the width/height manually. This has solved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

After try too many things, I discovered how to fix it.

I don't know why but when you set resible false, the screen automaticaly gains a extra space below and in the right side. To fix it, you should set the image background bigger than screen width and height, for example if you are using 900x600 in your anchor pane, you should set your image to 920x620.

One more time, I don't know why is it happening, but this was the only way that I've found to fix it whitout using css.

Comment: I found a better solution. Check my answer.

Answer (score 0):

1. Set maxSize() and minSize to the size of the image:

   ```
   Scene scene = new Scene(new StackPane());  

   private final static double IMG_WIDTH = 900d;
   private final static double IMG_HEIGHT = 600d;

   LoginManager loginManager = new LoginManager(scene);
   loginManager.showLoginScreen();

   primaryStage.setResizable(false);
   primaryStage.setMaxWidth(IMG_WIDTH);
   primaryStage.setMaxHeight(IMG_HEIGHT);
   primaryStage.setMinWidth(IMG_WIDTH);
   primaryStage.setMinHeight(IMG_HEIGHT);

   primaryStage.setScene(scene);
   primaryStage.show();
   ```
2. Check the size of the image if it really is 900x600.

Comment: I did everything you said but still the same.

Answer (score 0):

use this solution but it only works for jdk8

```
  Stage.sizeToScene();
```

Answer (score -1):

Stage.sizeToScene();

it works perfectly.

Comment: please don't spam the answer section with duplications of answers :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).