# Extra Space in JavaFX

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I was working on a JavaFX application, and while working on the layout, I noticed a weird extra space in my scene. I did not ask for the space to be there, and I made sure that the padding and spacing was set to `0`. Here's the (extremely stripped down) version of the code:

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.TextArea;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

public class Test extends Application {

    private static final int PREF_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int PREF_HEIGHT = 300;

    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea text = new TextArea();
        text.setMinWidth(PREF_WIDTH);
        text.setPrefWidth(PREF_WIDTH);
        text.setMaxWidth(PREF_WIDTH);
        text.setMinHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);
        text.setPrefHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);
        text.setMaxHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);

        VBox contentPane = new VBox();
        contentPane.getChildren().addAll(text);

        VBox mainPane = new VBox();
        mainPane.getChildren().addAll(contentPane);

        Scene scene = new Scene(mainPane);
        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Resulting in:

[image]

What I really want is no space at all.

---

Why is this happening? How do you get rid of it?

Comment: Are you sure it's not an artifact of the display tool? How about changing the color to red or so and seeing if it spans the entire window?

Comment: This is because of `primaryStage.setResizable(false);`; set it to `true` and see, if the space is gone. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14759182/anchorpane-shows-a-white-border-when-setresizable-is-false-javafx).

Comment: @pzaenger You seem to be right. Now the question is how to not allow resizing while still keeping that effect.

Comment: Did you check the accepted answer within the link I have provided? If yes, did it work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed a couple of things and this works well:

```
public class Test extends Application {

    private static final int PREF_WIDTH = 600;
    private static final int PREF_HEIGHT = 300;

    @Override
    public void start(Stage primaryStage) {
        TextArea text = new TextArea();
        BorderPane content = new BorderPane(text);
        Scene scene = new Scene(content, PREF_WIDTH, PREF_HEIGHT);

        primaryStage.setResizable(false);
        primaryStage.setScene(scene);
        primaryStage.show();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Maybe you can use this bit of code. In this case I have set the width and height of the scene. You can also add other widgets to the `BorderPane`.

Answer (score -1):

```
text.setMinWidth(PREF_WIDTH);
text.setPrefWidth(PREF_WIDTH);
text.setMaxWidth(PREF_WIDTH);
text.setMinHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);
text.setPrefHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);
text.setMaxHeight(PREF_HEIGHT);
```

remote above lines

Comment: I still get a space at the bottom.